# java conversion: MultivalueMap<String,String> to Map<String,String[]>

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with Java and Spring.

I'm obtaining a `MultiValueMap<String,String>`. This is helpful to me because I can store more than one value for a each `key`. But a library I'm using requires a type of `Map<String,String[]>` instead. More particularly I am working with a `ParameterMap`. How do I perform such conversion?

Comment: `MultiValueMap<String, String>` is a `Map<String, List<String>>` in itself, you can just iterate it. Or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 6):

Grab the map's entry set and collect it yourself:

```
Map<String, String[]> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, 
            e -> e.getValue().toArray(new String[e.getValue().size()])
        ));
```

Answer (score 4):

Map<String, String> registeredUserDetails = userInfo.entrySet().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get(0)));